# How to correctly annotate JPA enities with @OneToOne?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

Collegues, I have two tables and select to get `CHAIN`:

`SELECT OD_CHAINS_REQ.CHAIN 
FROM OD_CHAINS_REQ
  JOIN od_face_accs
    ON od_face_accs.ID = OD_CHAINS_REQ.ACCOUNT
WHERE od_face_accs.ACNT='1608290029'
ORDER BY OD_CHAINS_REQ.NUM;`

There are less than 10 records in `OD_CHAINS_REQ` table, and more than 1000 in `od_face_accs`table.

I'am trying to execute this select over JPA. But, as I understan, i need to created entity `OdChainsReqEntity`:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "OD_CHAINS_REQ", schema = "", catalog = "")
    @IdClass(OdChainsReqEntityPK.class)
    public class OdChainsReqEntity {
        private Integer chain;
        private Integer num;
        private Integer account;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "CHAIN")
        public Integer getChain() {
            return chain;
        }

        public void setChain(Integer chain) {
            this.chain = chain;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "NUM")
        public Integer getNum() {
            return num;
        }

        public void setNum(Integer num) {
            this.num = num;
        }

        @Id
        @Column(name = "ACCOUNT")
        public Integer getAccount() {
            return account;
        }

        public void setAccount(Integer account) {
            this.account = account;
        }


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private OdFaceAccsEntity odFaceAccsEntity;
    public OdFaceAccsEntity getOdFaceAccsEntity() {
        return odFaceAccsEntity;
    }

    public void setOdFaceAccsEntity(OdFaceAccsEntity odFaceAccsEntity) {
        this.odFaceAccsEntity = odFaceAccsEntity;
    }

    /*@Overrides*/*/

}
```

and `OdFaceAccsEntity` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OD_FACE_ACCS", schema = "", catalog = "")
public class OdFaceAccsEntity {
    private Integer id;
    private String acnt;



    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ACNT")
    public String getAcnt() {
        return acnt;
    }

    public void setAcnt(String acnt) {
        this.acnt = acnt;
    }

    /*@Overrides*/


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn (referencedColumnName = "ACCOUNT")
    private OdChainsReqEntity odChainsReqEntity;

    public OdChainsReqEntity getOdChainsReqEntity() {
        return odChainsReqEntity;
    }

    public void setOdChainsReqEntity(OdChainsReqEntity odChainsReqEntity) {
        this.odChainsReqEntity = odChainsReqEntity;
    }

}
```

So I'm trying to get Chain using test

```
 @Test
    public void getChainByDepoAcc() throws Exception {

        OdFaceAccsEntity odFaceAccsEntity = new OdFaceAccsEntity();
        odFaceAccsEntity.setAcnt("1608290029");


        List<OdFaceAccsEntity> odFaceAccsEntities = odFaceAccsDAO.getAcc(odFaceAccsEntity);

        for (int i = 0; i < odFaceAccsEntities.size(); i++) {
            LOG.info(odFaceAccsEntities.get(i).getId());
            LOG.info(odFaceAccsEntities.get(i).getOdChainsReqEntity().getChain());
        }
    }
```

But it returns the exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type
>   for: com.alcap.app.JPA.Entities.OdFaceAccsEntity, at table:
>   OD_CHAINS_REQ, for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(odFaceAccsEntity)]

How to correctly specify the association in enities to avoid exception?

**UPDATE**
The last DAO implementation I've tried:

```
  @Transactional(value = "txMan", readOnly = true)
    public List <OdChainsReqEntity> getOdChainsReqByDEPOAcc(String in$depoAccnt) {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT cre FROM OdChainsReqEntity cre " +
            "join OdFaceAccsEntity fae on fae.id = cre.account "+
           "where fae.acnt = :depoAcc");
         query.setParameter("depoAcc", in$depoAccnt);
        List<OdChainsReqEntity> result =  query.getResultList();
        return result;
    }
```

Also i tried this one (but i don't know if it suitable for `join` select):

```
public List<OdChainsReqEntity> getOdChainsReqByAnyParam(OdChainsReqEntity odChainsReqEntity) {

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<OdChainsReqEntity> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(OdChainsReqEntity.class);
        Root<OdChainsReqEntity> entityRoot = criteriaQuery.from(OdChainsReqEntity.class);

        Predicate criteria = cb.conjunction();

        if (odChainsReqEntity.getChain() != null) {Predicate p = cb.equal(entityRoot.get("chain"), odChainsReqEntity.getChain()); criteria = cb.and(criteria, p);}
        if (odChainsReqEntity.getNum() != null) {Predicate p = cb.equal(entityRoot.get("num"), odChainsReqEntity.getNum()); criteria = cb.and(criteria, p);}
        if (odChainsReqEntity.getAccount() != null) {Predicate p = cb.equal(entityRoot.get("account"), odChainsReqEntity.getAccount()); criteria = cb.and(criteria, p);}


        criteriaQuery.where(criteria);
        List<OdChainsReqEntity> result = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();

        return result;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted your DAO implementation. Assuming it is correct, one of the following might be the problem:

1. You defined the `access type` incosistently. You are placing the mapping annotations (`@Column`, `@OneToOne`, ...) on getter methods as well as fields of the entities which is not defined by specification. So move the mapping annotations either on fields or on getters but not on both:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "OD_FACE_ACCS", schema = "", catalog = "")
   @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
   public class OdFaceAccsEntity {
       private Integer id;
       private String acnt;
       private OdChainsReqEntity odChainsReqEntity;

       @Id
       public Integer getId() {
           return id;
       }

       public void setId(Integer id) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       public String getAcnt() {
           return acnt;
       }

       public void setAcnt(String acnt) {
          this.acnt = acnt;
       }

       /*@Overrides*/

       @OneToOne(mappedBy = "odFaceAccsEntity")
       public OdChainsReqEntity getOdChainsReqEntity() {
           return odChainsReqEntity;
       }

       public void setOdChainsReqEntity(OdChainsReqEntity odChainsReqEntity) {
           this.odChainsReqEntity = odChainsReqEntity;
        }

   }



   @Entity
   @Table(name = "OD_CHAINS_REQ", schema = "", catalog = "")
   @IdClass(OdChainsReqEntityPK.class)
   @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
   public class OdChainsReqEntity {
       private Integer chain;
       private Integer num;
       private Integer account;
       private OdFaceAccsEntity odFaceAccsEntity;

       // the rest of the code here

       @OneToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT", referencedColumnName = "ID")
       public OdFaceAccsEntity getOdFaceAccsEntity() {
           return odFaceAccsEntity;
       }

       // the rest of the code

   }
   ```

As you can see, I moved all the necessary mapping annotations on the getter methods (I just removed some annotations to save space because they are there by default).

2. The second problem is that you placed the `@JoinColumn` annotation on both entities which is not correct. You have to place this annotation only on one side of the relationship which is supposed to be the owner of the relationship; in one-to-one relationships it doesn't matter on which side you place the annotation. It is required the other side of the relationship be mapped as `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "")`. I just made the `OdFaceAccsEntity` entity to be the inverse side of the relationship and changed accordingly (see the `@OneToOne` in code above). If you don't want that this entity be an inverse side just reverse the annotations

Here are the sections of the [JPA 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf)  you might read to understand how to map correctly:

- **2.3 Access Type**
- **2.10.1 Bidirectional OneToOne Relationships**

Comment: Try with this query instead of yours: `SELECT cre FROM OdChainsReqEntity cre JOIN cre.odFaceAccsEntity fae  where fae.acnt = :depoAcc`. (This is inner join => if the tables do not have matching columns you'll get empty result set; in that case you can use left join. The criteria part is not complete I think; but try this one first.

Comment: i added `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "odFaceAccsEntity")` to the `OdFaceAccsEntity` class, but recive popup `Cannot resolve attribute 'odFaceAccsEntity'`.

Comment: Uff... Thank you, @ujulu. All the best to you.